# Why isn't my method noticing what is being help by a spot in a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I am writing a program that will allow you to book a seat on a flight. It asks the user how many rows are available, then it makes a 2d array with 4 columns and how ever many rows the user specifies. Then my program prompts the user to choose how man seats he wants and then what row and column he wants those seats to be. then it will change the value of the position in the array form "-" to "X". That all works beautifuly, but I'm running into issues when I am trying to use a method to cancel the reserved seating. I have it so it props the user, if he wants to cancel a seat and how many, then I get the row and column that he wants to cancle. So then it checks to see if that spot in the array has a value of "-" or "X" if it has a "-" it displays a message saying that they need to input a seat that is reserved and if it has a "X" the it changes it to "-" to show that its open. But for some reason if i put in a position that is take or has "X" as a value it says that there isn't, what did i do wrong?

Here is my code:

This is my cancle method

```
public void CancleSeat(String[][] SC, String can, int c, int r, int Seats, int an){
    FillArray(SC);
    if (can.equals("No")){
        System.out.println("OK, no cancelations for you!");
    }
    else if (can.equals("Yes")){
        System.out.println("How many seats would you like to cancel?");
        an = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < an; i++){
            System.out.println("What row is your seat in that you would like to cancle?");
            r = scanner.nextInt();
            r = r - 1;
            System.out.println("What colum is your seat in that you would like to cancle?");
            c = scanner.nextInt();
            c = c -1;
            if (SC[r][c].equals("-")){
                System.out.println("That seat isn't researved pleas pick a different seat");
                System.out.println("What row is your seat in that you would like to cancle?");
                r = scanner.nextInt();
                r = r - 1;
                System.out.println("What colum is your seat in that you would like to cancle?");
                c = scanner.nextInt();
                c = c - 1;
            }
            else if (SC[r][c].equals("X") || SC[r][c].equals("x")){
                SC[r][c] = "-";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what i am using to call it in the driver class.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to canlce any reservations?");
cancle = scanner.next();
Seeting cancler = new Seeting(numSeatsBooking, row, colum, cancle, openSeats, answer);
cancler.CancleSeat(SeetingChart, cancle, colum, row, numSeatsBooking, answer);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You ask for the r and c again in the if statement, but you don't use those values. Maybe use a while loop instead of an if to make them keep entering row and column until they put in a seat that is reserved.

Comment: @Sesame I agree with that; however, I don't think that is relevant to the OP's question.  I think OP is entering a row and column where he is expecting an 'X', but the program is printing out that it's a '-'.

@TravisWittmann: what is your current input and output?

Also, most of your arguments to your `CancleSeat` method are overwritten and are therefore irrelevant.

Comment: For example I would print out a table where row 1 colum 1 has an "X" and if I try and cancel it out putting in colum 1 and row 1 it s says that there isn't an "X" in that location

Comment: If you entered in the right coordinates the first time, you should print out your array and see what it looks like. If you put in the wrong coordinates first, see my comment above.